# What causes urllib2 to throw a HTTPError: HTTP Error 505: HTTP Version Not Supported?

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm getting an error when trying to load a webpage. It's an error 505.

Right now, I'm using urlopen(). Do I need to use another method of opening the webpage?

I read something about having to use httplib.HTTP instead?

```
HTTPError: HTTP Error 505: HTTP Version Not Supported
```

Comment: Why use urllib2? I'd check out Requests. Brilliant library. Fantastic lib that solves most of the common issues working with urllib2.

Comment: I always try to use a 'lower-level' or 'more direct' route when I can. Thank-you to both of you.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong. The server doesn't support HTTP/1.1, indeed. It looks like `httplib.HTTP` would use version 1.0 instead indeed. Let me see what I can dig up.

Comment: Send a HTTP/1.0 request instead, see linked dupe.

Comment: Which one of these 2 ideas suggested would be ideal?

Comment: Update: Requests worked nicely.

Comment: @macdonjo: I am glad, and frankly somewhat surprised, to hear that! Because `requests` ultimately uses the same HTTP version as `urllib2` would, because both use `httplib.HTTPConnection`, not `httplib.HTTP`.